# Coding standards and design patterns in PHPSpec library

Tags: php, design-patterns, coding-style, phpspec

I really like the codebase of PHPSpec.

Could any of you guys mention any standards and/or design patterns that are prominent in this library as that is how I want my code to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but it looks like the ZF coding standards:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html#coding-standard.overview

Comment: Yeah I guess that covers the standards. What I find really different in PHPSpec code from ZendFramework code is that PHPSpec classes are really small.